Attribute table in Print Layout
I want to add to Print Layout a pie chart and table summarizing total area of damage that certain area suffered during last flood. I want to show total area split on two classes: damaged and intact. I added attribute table to the print layout but currently QGIS shows area of each feature, not total area of all features within class.
What expression should I use to display only two rows with split on two classes?


Have a look at aggregates functions: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregates-functions Without more details on your data structure, its a bit difficult to help

Can you use the Group Stats plugin?
